# how to run a powershell script and a batch script in a batch script?

Tags: powershell, command-line, command, powershell-2.0, command-prompt

i have controller batch file named oneclick.bat, code as below:

```
rem batch controller
rem wait for email input for ssh key generation...
rem call copyEnv.bat
call generateSshKey.bat %1
call gitClone.bat
```

in generateSshKey.bat， i start a powershell script like this:

```
rem make sure powershell is able to run 
powershell.exe  set-executionpolicy remotesigned

rem start powershell and add ssh key to the server by ui aotumation
powershell.exe -noe -file SetSSHKeytoServer.ps1
```

and then  gitClone.bat did not run in the command window

**how can i get the gitClone.bat run?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to return to a calling script you shouldn't run PowerShell with an option that prevents it from returning. Remove `-noe` from the last line of `generateSshKey.bat`.

```
-NoExit
    Does not exit after running startup commands.
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ansgar Wiechers pointed out, the **-noe** (short for **-NoExit**) is keeps the PowerShell session open, so **generateSshKey.bat** doesn't exit, and **oneclick.bat** doesn't get past the line that called it.

If you specifically *want* the powershell session that runs **SetSSHKeytoServer.ps1** to remain active (since you used the **-noe** switch the second time but not the first time, I'm inferring that this was deliberate), you could change

```
call generateSshKey.bat %1
```

to

```
start generateSshKey.bat %1
```

Note that this means that **oneclick.bat** won't wait for **generateSshKey.bat** to finish before calling **gitClone.bat**, so if you need to run them in sequence, this won't work. It will work as long as it's okay for **gitClone.bat** to start while **generateSshKey.bat** is still running.

Comment: thanks @Adi Inbar; i need the batch scripts execute in sequence. Ansgar Wiechers's answer works for me.